# Do I need to recompile command-line utilities after upgrading Mac OS X?

Tags: mac, unix

This is probably a trivial question, but I have the [GNU coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) installed, along with many Python packages and some other things.  I was expecting that I may have to re-compile or re-install some/all of these things since OS X 10.8 / Xcode 4.4 has a newer version of GCC, etc.  However, everything seems to work fine so far.  Should I recompile everything anyway?  Am I risking some bug down the line?  Or since the programs run fine, should everything be alright?  I don't fully understand how exactly this works post-compile.

Edit: Both Coreutils and Python were built from source, then Python packages were installed with `pip` or the equivalent.  Everything *seems* to work fine, I'm just a bit paranoid.

Comment: How did you install these tools? Using a package manager? Which one?

Comment: Edited to clarify.

Comment: If you really want a precise answer, then you need to read all of the Release Notes for the software that was updated.  Then you will know if any changes affect your compiled software.  In general, if you have not yet encountered a problem in the compiled packages, then a new GCC would not necessitate recompilation.  And if you do recompile, you should check for updated source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be fine. The old libraries should still be there, unless you're copying some ~/bin folder back to a fresh install.